Which plant was used as Athelas in LOTR / Hobbit movies?
There is already an exquisite thread concerning the plant described in the book
link here and its relative real life counterpart,
but my question is about the one actually used in the movies .
Any information anyone?

A screenshot: https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Athelas?file=Athelas.jpg

@BenBolker - Alas broken.

I think it was an attempt at the picture here (scroll down) https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Athelas but it's not a lot better if any.

Here's lightened, focus-tweaked attempt from 1:08  into the DVD version. https://i.sstatic.net/TM0cSwKJ.png

@Mars_87: you're not supposed to include answers in your question ... feel free to post that information as a new answer.

Thanks Ben, posted now as a new answer

The second-to-last post here claims that

Actually, the plant used in the movies is white thyme. It grows everywhere, can be used medicinally, is considered an invasive plant and is also given to the pigs to eat. It is also found in purple

However, the images they show are of Thymus serpyllum (Wikipedia), whereas the only references I can find to invasive thyme in NZ are about Thymus vulgarum (wild thyme) (Wikipedia), e.g. here.
The last post says it's common myrtle (Myrtus communis).
Hard to tell scale from the screenshot: this picture suggests the flowers are quite small (~ 1 cm in diameter?)


top left: LoTR still capture (from https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Athelas?file=Athelas.jpg)
top right: common myrtle, Giancarlo Dessì, CC-BY-SA, https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Myrtus_communis10.jpg
bottom left: elfin thyme, KENPEI, CC-BY-SA, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thymus_serpyllum#/media/File:Thymus_serpyllum_var_albus1.jpg
bottom right: wild thyme, Ferran Turmo Gort, CC-BY-NC-SA, https://inaturalist.nz/photos/48088

New guess: https://identify.plantnet.org/ thinks Bacopa repens (Sw.) Wettst. Creeping waterhyssop. But is the habitat wet enough ... ??
(More guesses from PlantNet: Acleisanthes longiflora A.Gray
(Angel trumpet), Silene pinetorum Boiss. & Heldr., Bacopa monnieri (L.) Wettst. (Monnier's hedge hyssop) ...
Water hyssop from  Gerlinde (cc-by-sa) - Sep 13, 2021:


It isn't thyme or myrtle, both have flowers quite different to the ones seen in the photo. Myrtle would have hair-like stamens in the middle of the flower obscuring the middle of the flower. Thyme has only 4 petals, and the three at the bottom are larger. The plant in question has 5 petals, is semi-woody at best (given it's droopy nature). I think I have some of this growing in my garden, but damned if I know the name. I think the Biology SE or perhaps the Gardening SE might know.

Go out in your garden and use a plant ID app like iNaturalist ?

I shall try and see if I can locate it. No flowers at the moment I think unfortunately.

Definitely not anemone. Wood sorrel is Oxalis, has clover-like leaves, flowers are close but too small relative to Aragorn's hand, and habit of the plant is wrong. I think Bacopa is pretty close, AKA Sutera. There are dark spots on each petal, which might give it away to a better gardener than me. There's a fairly good chance it is a reasonably common garden plant. Pity we don't have a clearer shot.

Hi everyone,
together with this thread I started in parallel a topic on a Bothanical forum to check the hypotheses gathered and get advise as we move forward.
The current advise is to exclude Lamiaceae family, so we can exclude Thyme

Current advise seems towards Chaenostoma cordatum or a white Periwinkle species. Here are some images https://www.inaturalist.org/observations?place_id=any&taxon_id=501464

Narrowing those observations to New Zealand: https://www.inaturalist.org/observations?place_id=6803&taxon_id=501464

Any advice from more experienced forum members on whether it's worth editing this to clean up/remove unfounded speculations and include just the most likely candidates?

According to the European Botanical Forum I'm in touch with,
the hypothesis of Chaenostoma cordatum has been confirmed.
The actual suggestion leads towards the cv. Snowflake, with small flowers.
Here some pictures narrowed to the NZ landscape, thanks to @Ben Bolker
https://www.inaturalist.org/observations?place_id=6803&taxon_id=501464

It would be better to include any relevant images within your answer itself, rather than just linking to a page on another site where they can currently be viewed. A direct quote of what you were told by the European Botanical Forum would also be appreciated.

I would edit to include the images in-line, but they're not explicitly licensed for re-use ("© David Rayner, all rights reserved"), so I'm not sure that would be OK.
